# Send Out Of Stock Products to trash

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

There is a feature in WooCommerce to hide out of stock product from shop. However, this feature only works if I am using native WooCommerce shortcodes and does not work if other plugins are being being used to display products on other parts of the website.

So, I think trashing the product would be a better way to get rid of the Out Of Stock products for good. **I do not want a permanent delete** in case I want to make work easier and restore those products in the future but if there is no other way I would welcome it.

I am just learning a little PHP. Let me know if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

> As in WordPress all the thing are treated as post with different
>   `post_type`, So whenever a post/product is updated [`save_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) is
>   called.

```
function wh_trashOutOfStockProduct($post_id, $post, $update) {

    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);

    // If this isn't a 'product' post, don't update it.
    if ('product' != $post_type)
        return;
    $product = wc_get_product($post_id);
    //if product is Out of Stock trash it
    if (!$product->is_in_stock()) {
        wp_trash_post($post_id);
    }
}

add_action('save_post', 'wh_trashOutOfStockProduct', 10, 3);
```

*Code goes in `function.php` file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*

---

**UPDATED**
*One time use function*

```
add_action('wp', 'wh_trashAllProductOnce');

function wh_trashAllProductOnce()
{
    $params = [
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'product'
    ];
    $wc_query = new WP_Query($params);

    if ($wc_query->have_posts()) :
        while ($wc_query->have_posts()) :
            $wc_query->the_post();
            $product_id = get_the_ID();
            $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
            //if product is Out of Stock trash it
            if (!$product->is_in_stock())
            {
                wp_trash_post($product_id);
            }
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    else:
        _e('No Products');
    endif;
}
```

*Add the above code in active theme `functions.php` file and run your website **only once then delete the above code**, It 'll trash all the out of stock product.*

---

**UPDATED**

If you wish to keep the code for longer time then let reduce the query and the time of execution.

```
add_action('admin_init', 'wh_trashAllProductOnce');

function wh_trashAllProductOnce() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    //if loggedin user does not have admin previlage
    if (!user_can($current_user, 'administrator')) {
        return;
    }
    $params = [
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    ];
    $wc_query = new WP_Query($params);
    if ($wc_query->have_posts()) :
        while ($wc_query->have_posts()) :
            $wc_query->the_post();
            $product_id = get_the_ID();
            $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
            //if product is Out of Stock trash it
            if (!$product->is_in_stock()) {
                wp_trash_post($product_id);
            }
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
}
```

*Add the above code in active theme `functions.php` file and whenever an admin login to the dashboard and access any backend page this function will be trigger.*

> Please Note: **It is recommended to use any of the above method for
>   one time only, or whenever you need just un-comment the function use
>   it and then again comment it.**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your assistance but it does not trash the products. I am thinking there might be an issue with here "  if (!$product->is_in_stock())".      I know a little c# transferring knowledge I would think it would be                          IF product = "outofstock" THEN trash

Comment: @Ryon: do you want to trash all the existing outofstock product? and you have simple product or variable product? and `is_in_stock()` is a method with return `bool`.

Comment: All Existing products should be trashed too. All products are simple.

Comment: @Ryon: I have updated my answer, please check, but remember to remove the above code after usage.

Comment: I tested it to see why it is a one time code. It ill not allow any product to be restored from the trash BUT when the code is removed the products are not automatically sent to trash. I have decided to keep the code active at all times since it solves the issue. Please advice me if it is wise to keep the code.

Comment: I have added another function with `admin_init` hook use that one insted. the adverse effect will be if you have 1000 product then MySQL 'll fetch it and loop it and then update the db as needed, which will make you backend too too slow. and if you use `wp` hook then depending upon your product count page-speed will be affected and user dropout rate will be increased. So use it when needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
   add_filter( 'woocommerce_debug_tools',  'tools' );
/**
 * Tools we add to WC
 * @param  array $tools
 * @return array
 */
function tools( $tools ) {
    $tools['delete_products'] = array(
        'name'      => __( 'Delete OutofStock Products','your-text-domain'),
        'button'    => __( 'Delete OutofStock products','your-text-domain' ),
        'desc'      => __( 'This tool will delete OutofStock .', 'your-text-domain' ),
        'callback'  => array( $this, 'delete_products' )
    );
    return $tools;
}
/**
 * Delete OutofStock Products
 */
function delete_products() {
    global $wpdb;
            $wpdb->query( "DELETE p FROM {$wpdb->posts} p join {$wpdb->postmeta} pm on p.ID = pm.post_id WHERE p.post_type = 'product' and pm.meta_key='_stock_status' and pm.meta_value='outofstock'");
    echo '<div class="updated"><p>' . sprintf( __( 'Out of stock Products Deleted', 'your-text-domain' ) ) . '</p></div>';
}
```

You can do this by one click on tools menu under Woocommerce -> System Status, see screenshot [image]

Comment: Wow this is smart coding. I would however, I have to manually delete the product just the same. The aim to for the products to disappear once the stock hits zero. If there is no way to send it to trash, I would work with a permanent delete.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The code did not exactly solve the issue so I used @Raunak Gupta Solution instead.